# Laravel - Filter the relation of a relation if it exists

Tags: laravel

I have an **ObjectA**. The Object A has a `OneToOne` relationship with another **ObjectB**. Object B can have another `hasOne` relationship to an **ObjectC**.

| Object A | Object B | Object C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id (int) | id (int) | id (int) |
| name (string) | meta_data (string) | additinal_meta_data_description (string) |
| object_b_id (int) |  | is_something (boolean) |
| is_something (boolean) |  | object_b_id |

**Goal:** I would like to filter!

1. give me all objects A together with objects B that are A.is_something TRUE.
2. At the same time I would like to get the relation to Object C with. If one exists!

**Sub-goal:** All objects found that have a relationship C should be prioritized and appear at the top of the list. Is this possible at all?

**My Query:**

```php
$r = ObjectA::where([['is_something', '=', true]]
     ->whereHas('objectB', function($q) => use($isSomething = true) {
       $q->objectC->where('is_something', $isSomething);
     });

//----

class ObjectB extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function objectC()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ObjectC::class);
    }
}
```

**Problem** I got Exception: `Property [objectC] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.`

Comment: Could you please post ObjectB model code?

Comment: @manix Thanks for comment. I add the model ObjectB to my question.

Comment: So, you wanna get a list of all objectA's which have objectB that actually have objectC only?

Comment: @MarwaneEzzaze Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result query if I understood correctly :

```
$results = ObjectA::where('is_something', true)
->whereHas('objectB', function($subQ) {
    $subQ->whereRelation('objectC', 'is_something', true);
})
->get();
```

reference for the whereRelation : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#inline-relationship-existence-queries

Comment: Thank you very much Sir! It works!  The magic comes from the `whereRelation()` method?

Comment: Glad it worked, and no, you could also do it with another whereHas